# How to change the value in h:commandlink onclick

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to implement h:commandlink in my project. I need to change the value "Follow" to "Following" in the commandlink once the user clicks it. How do i do that? Can someone help me with this? Thanks for your time and help in advance.

```
<h:commandlink id="followdoc" action="Usermanger.followdoctor" value="Follow" />
```

Usermanager is my jsf managed bean class and followdoctor is a method in bean class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this at the client side, just grab JavaScript. After all, JSF ends up as plain HTML in webbrowser (rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*, you'll understand what I mean).

```
<h:commandLink value="Follow" action="#{bean.followDoctor}" onclick="this.innerHTML='Following'" />
```

But if you want to change (and if necessary memorize/persist) this in the server side, then just make it a bean property so that you can change it in the action method.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{bean.linkValue}" action="#{bean.followDoctor}" />
```

with

```
private String linkValue;

public Bean() {
    this.linkValue = "Follow"; // Preinitialize it somehow.
}

public String followDoctor() {
    this.linkValue = "Following";
    // ...
}
```